# Has this user been notified why he’s unable to ask questions?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

The user Mozibur Ullah posted the following:

> Do you still feel the term Jewish/Israel lobby is 'anti-semitic'; do you favour one term over the other? Or is neither advisable - please advise; I'm sorry to pester you like this, but given that you've tarnished my name and reputation with the slur of anti-semitism I feel I should clear it; after all, thats why I've banned from asking questions on this site. This is of course unjust. Did you have a hand in that?

Has this user been notified of why he’s banned from asking questions? If not, he should be notified so that he doesn’t blame the wrong parties for doing so. If he has, and if he is blaming the wrong parties, that should be clarified.

Normally the reasons for bans are kept private to protect the privacy of the user, but he’s decided to make it a public issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user was automatically banned from asking questions. The error message they received includes a link to the [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) help article, that explains the basics of the ban and offers some help on how to get out of it. They either didn't follow the link or didn't read the article carefully.

I've posted a comment letting them know the ban is automatic. Hopefully, this time they'll take the time to read the help article.

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile and sending the user a note.

Comment: Oh well, it didn't help. At least we tried.

Comment: By the way: You can tell if a user is suspended by a mod or has an automatic block from the system by looking at their reputation score. It will show as 1 while the user is suspended by a moderator and be unaffected during automatic blocks. Also, automatic blocks only apply to specific features (asking, answering, suggesting edits and review). Mod suspensions block any form of contribution. If they can still post comments, then they are not suspended by a moderator.